# Random Token Generator: Class level or Method level?

Tags: java

I want to generate random token using SecureRandom class, so where should I create the object of SecureRandom class?(method level or class level)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you use it. If you need it only a few times, create it in the method where you need it. That keeps your code simpler.

If you need it so often, that the overhead of creating the object is a concern, create it once and store it in the object or class.